# Adding path to base url in Spring Rest Docs?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-restdocs

I have following configuration to use with Rest Docs:

```
webTestClient = buildWebClient().mutate()
  .filter(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
  .baseUrl("https://api.my-domain.com/")
  .build()
```

In my case I use path prefix to my service - `service/foo` since I use k8s ingress and my service is served on path offset.

Is there a way to insert such prefix without modifying production code?

Related documentation fragment:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#configuration-uris-webtestclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To document another URI than the one called to generate documentation, you have to write your own `OperationPreprocessor`. There are some predefined like `Preprocessors.modifyUris` but it does not allow to modify the request path.

Check below the webTestClient configuration and the `URIUpdaterOperationRequest` class. Code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/Query-Interface/SO-Answers/blob/master/java/spring/rest-docs-modify-uripath/src/test/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java

```
public void init() throws Exception {
    final URIUpdaterPreprocessor preprocessor = new URIUpdaterPreprocessor();
    webTestClient = webTestClient.mutate()
        .filter((documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)
                .operationPreprocessors()
                    .withRequestDefaults(preprocessor)
                    .withResponseDefaults(prettyPrint()))
                )
        .build();
}

private static final class URIUpdaterPreprocessor
    implements OperationPreprocessor {

    @Override
    public OperationRequest preprocess(OperationRequest request) {
        return new URIUpdaterOperationRequest(request);
    }

    @Override
    public OperationResponse preprocess(OperationResponse response) {
        return response;
    }

}

private static final class URIUpdaterOperationRequest
    implements OperationRequest {

    private OperationRequest delegate;

    public URIUpdaterOperationRequest(OperationRequest request) {
        delegate = request;
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return delegate.getContent();
    }

    public String getContentAsString() {
        return delegate.getContentAsString();
    }

    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        return delegate.getHeaders();
    }

    public HttpMethod getMethod() {
        return delegate.getMethod();
    }

    public Parameters getParameters() {
        return delegate.getParameters();
    }

    public Collection<OperationRequestPart> getParts() {
        return delegate.getParts();
    }

    public URI getUri() {
        URI sourceUri = delegate.getUri();
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(sourceUri);
        return builder
            .host(sourceUri.getHost())
            .replacePath("/service/foo"+sourceUri.getPath())
            .build().toUri();
    }

    public Collection<RequestCookie> getCookies() {
        return delegate.getCookies();
    }
}
```

I think another possibilty is to update the mustache templates so as to add a prefix before all request path references. The default templates are [located here on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/tree/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates).